# PHP/HTML Rating System inside a Loop of Movies

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Sorry if my question is too dummy but it's being a while I'm trying to include a rating system in a page with several movies.

This page is basically a result set of a database query and I'm just displaying a list of movies on the page (HTML/PHP), nothing really too hard to do.

Include a rating system is OK and works fine for the first movie I have on this page.

For the second movie and on, this is where the rating system starting working messy.

Or the rate on the second movie on rates only the first movie or I can show the rating for all movies but not use it like in the first movie of the list.

**What I have tried:**

I included one form to each movie I'm displaying on the page and by doing this I'm able to get for instance the id of the movie individually.

The problem aparently is not on the rating systems that are available on google, I've tried several of then and they all work fine if you consider individually on the page.

**Rating Systems used (just example can be any rating system):**

1. [css-star-ratings](https://freefrontend.com/css-star-ratings/) (Mert Cukuren): with HTML/CSS, (this one is the one I would really like to use), I'm able to display it on the page, recover database values to display score normally, but I'm stuck when I try to rate the second movie on, always the first movie is rated).
2. [php-rating-system](http://codingpassiveincome.com/php-rating-system) with HTML, Ajax and MySql, also work fine for the first movie, for the second movie on I can't simply even rate the movie though...

**Follow the minimal code I could register here taking out all of my personal business logic:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Rating System</title>
    <!-- 01 - Styling to the Rating System -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rating_movies.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- 02 - Receives the POST submit in order to capture the suggestion_id (that's fine)
          and rating (that's working only for the first movie) -->
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['suggestion_id'])){
        echo 'suggestion_id: ' . $_POST['suggestion_id'] . ' rating: ' . $_POST['rating'];
    }
?>

<!-- 03 - HTML Initial part -->
<div class="content-area">
    <main>
        <section class="middle-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="avaliados-template">

                    <!-- 04 - PHP Loop on Approved Movies -->
                    <?php 

                        echo "</br>Here you can check suggestions I have approved so far</br></br>";

                        $select = "
                                    select suggestion_id, title, score
                                    from suggestions // any table on mysql
                                    where approved = 'Y'
                                    order by suggestion_date desc";

                        foreach( $wpdb->get_results($select) as $key => $row) {
                            $suggestion_id = $row->suggestion_id;
                            $title = $row->title;
                            $score = $row->score;
                            if(!isset($score)){$score=0;}
                            echo 'Title: '.$title.' suggestion_id: ' . $suggestion_id;

                            echo '</br></br>';
                    ?>

                    <!-- 05 - Here I have the rating system that is appearing for each movie -->
                    <form method="post">
                        <div class="container_face">
                            <div class="feedback">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Save Rating</button>
                                <!-- 06 - Here I'm saving the value on a hidden input, in order to capture the id of the movie -->
                                <!--      and this part is working fine to any movie on the list -->
                                <input type="hidden" id="suggestion_id" name="suggestion_id" value="<?php echo $suggestion_id; ?>">
                                <?php $_POST['suggestion_id'] = $suggestion_id; ?>
                                <div class="rating">
                                  <input type="radio" name="rating" value=5 id="rating-5">
                                  <label for="rating-5"></label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="rating" value=4 id="rating-4">
                                  <label for="rating-4"></label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="rating" value=3 id="rating-3">
                                  <label for="rating-3"></label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="rating" value=2 id="rating-2">
                                  <label for="rating-2"></label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="rating" value=1 id="rating-1">
                                  <label for="rating-1"></label>
                                  <div class="emoji-wrapper">
                                    <div class="emoji">
                                      <svg class="rating-0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                      <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b"/>
                                      <path d="M512 256c0 141.44-114.64 256-256 256-80.48 0-152.32-37.12-199.28-95.28 43.92 35.52 99.84 56.72 160.72 56.72 141.36 0 256-114.56 256-256 0-60.88-21.2-116.8-56.72-160.72C474.8 103.68 512 175.52 512 256z" fill="#f4c534"/>
                                      <ellipse transform="scale(-1) rotate(31.21 715.433 -595.455)" cx="166.318" cy="199.829" rx="56.146" ry="56.13" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <ellipse transform="rotate(-148.804 180.87 175.82)" cx="180.871" cy="175.822" rx="28.048" ry="28.08" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <ellipse transform="rotate(-113.778 194.434 165.995)" cx="194.433" cy="165.993" rx="8.016" ry="5.296" fill="#5a5f63"/>
                                      <ellipse transform="scale(-1) rotate(31.21 715.397 -1237.664)" cx="345.695" cy="199.819" rx="56.146" ry="56.13" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <ellipse transform="rotate(-148.804 360.25 175.837)" cx="360.252" cy="175.84" rx="28.048" ry="28.08" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <ellipse transform="scale(-1) rotate(66.227 254.508 -573.138)" cx="373.794" cy="165.987" rx="8.016" ry="5.296" fill="#5a5f63"/>
                                      <path d="M370.56 344.4c0 7.696-6.224 13.92-13.92 13.92H155.36c-7.616 0-13.92-6.224-13.92-13.92s6.304-13.92 13.92-13.92h201.296c7.696.016 13.904 6.224 13.904 13.92z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                    </svg>
                                      <svg class="rating-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                      <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b"/>
                                      <path d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z" fill="#f4c534"/>
                                      <path d="M328.4 428a92.8 92.8 0 0 0-145-.1 6.8 6.8 0 0 1-12-5.8 86.6 86.6 0 0 1 84.5-69 86.6 86.6 0 0 1 84.7 69.8c1.3 6.9-7.7 10.6-12.2 5.1z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <path d="M269.2 222.3c5.3 62.8 52 113.9 104.8 113.9 52.3 0 90.8-51.1 85.6-113.9-2-25-10.8-47.9-23.7-66.7-4.1-6.1-12.2-8-18.5-4.2a111.8 111.8 0 0 1-60.1 16.2c-22.8 0-42.1-5.6-57.8-14.8-6.8-4-15.4-1.5-18.9 5.4-9 18.2-13.2 40.3-11.4 64.1z" fill="#f4c534"/>
                                      <path d="M357 189.5c25.8 0 47-7.1 63.7-18.7 10 14.6 17 32.1 18.7 51.6 4 49.6-26.1 89.7-67.5 89.7-41.6 0-78.4-40.1-82.5-89.7A95 95 0 0 1 298 174c16 9.7 35.6 15.5 59 15.5z" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <path d="M396.2 246.1a38.5 38.5 0 0 1-38.7 38.6 38.5 38.5 0 0 1-38.6-38.6 38.6 38.6 0 1 1 77.3 0z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <path d="M380.4 241.1c-3.2 3.2-9.9 1.7-14.9-3.2-4.8-4.8-6.2-11.5-3-14.7 3.3-3.4 10-2 14.9 2.9 4.9 5 6.4 11.7 3 15z" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <path d="M242.8 222.3c-5.3 62.8-52 113.9-104.8 113.9-52.3 0-90.8-51.1-85.6-113.9 2-25 10.8-47.9 23.7-66.7 4.1-6.1 12.2-8 18.5-4.2 16.2 10.1 36.2 16.2 60.1 16.2 22.8 0 42.1-5.6 57.8-14.8 6.8-4 15.4-1.5 18.9 5.4 9 18.2 13.2 40.3 11.4 64.1z" fill="#f4c534"/>
                                      <path d="M155 189.5c-25.8 0-47-7.1-63.7-18.7-10 14.6-17 32.1-18.7 51.6-4 49.6 26.1 89.7 67.5 89.7 41.6 0 78.4-40.1 82.5-89.7A95 95 0 0 0 214 174c-16 9.7-35.6 15.5-59 15.5z" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <path d="M115.8 246.1a38.5 38.5 0 0 0 38.7 38.6 38.5 38.5 0 0 0 38.6-38.6 38.6 38.6 0 1 0-77.3 0z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <path d="M131.6 241.1c3.2 3.2 9.9 1.7 14.9-3.2 4.8-4.8 6.2-11.5 3-14.7-3.3-3.4-10-2-14.9 2.9-4.9 5-6.4 11.7-3 15z" fill="#fff"/>
                                    </svg>
                                      <svg class="rating-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                      <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b"/>
                                      <path d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z" fill="#f4c534"/>
                                      <path d="M336.6 403.2c-6.5 8-16 10-25.5 5.2a117.6 117.6 0 0 0-110.2 0c-9.4 4.9-19 3.3-25.6-4.6-6.5-7.7-4.7-21.1 8.4-28 45.1-24 99.5-24 144.6 0 13 7 14.8 19.7 8.3 27.4z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <path d="M276.6 244.3a79.3 79.3 0 1 1 158.8 0 79.5 79.5 0 1 1-158.8 0z" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <circle cx="340" cy="260.4" r="36.2" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <g fill="#fff">
                                        <ellipse transform="rotate(-135 326.4 246.6)" cx="326.4" cy="246.6" rx="6.5" ry="10"/>
                                        <path d="M231.9 244.3a79.3 79.3 0 1 0-158.8 0 79.5 79.5 0 1 0 158.8 0z"/>
                                      </g>
                                      <circle cx="168.5" cy="260.4" r="36.2" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <ellipse transform="rotate(-135 182.1 246.7)" cx="182.1" cy="246.7" rx="10" ry="6.5" fill="#fff"/>
                                    </svg>
                                      <svg class="rating-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b"/>
                                <path d="M407.7 352.8a163.9 163.9 0 0 1-303.5 0c-2.3-5.5 1.5-12 7.5-13.2a780.8 780.8 0 0 1 288.4 0c6 1.2 9.9 7.7 7.6 13.2z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                <path d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z" fill="#f4c534"/>
                                <g fill="#fff">
                                  <path d="M115.3 339c18.2 29.6 75.1 32.8 143.1 32.8 67.1 0 124.2-3.2 143.2-31.6l-1.5-.6a780.6 780.6 0 0 0-284.8-.6z"/>
                                  <ellipse cx="356.4" cy="205.3" rx="81.1" ry="81"/>
                                </g>
                                <ellipse cx="356.4" cy="205.3" rx="44.2" ry="44.2" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                <g fill="#fff">
                                  <ellipse transform="scale(-1) rotate(45 454 -906)" cx="375.3" cy="188.1" rx="12" ry="8.1"/>
                                  <ellipse cx="155.6" cy="205.3" rx="81.1" ry="81"/>
                                </g>
                                <ellipse cx="155.6" cy="205.3" rx="44.2" ry="44.2" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                <ellipse transform="scale(-1) rotate(45 454 -421.3)" cx="174.5" cy="188" rx="12" ry="8.1" fill="#fff"/>
                                </svg>
                                      <svg class="rating-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                      <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b"/>
                                      <path d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z" fill="#f4c534"/>
                                      <path d="M232.3 201.3c0 49.2-74.3 94.2-74.3 94.2s-74.4-45-74.4-94.2a38 38 0 0 1 74.4-11.1 38 38 0 0 1 74.3 11.1z" fill="#e24b4b"/>
                                      <path d="M96.1 173.3a37.7 37.7 0 0 0-12.4 28c0 49.2 74.3 94.2 74.3 94.2C80.2 229.8 95.6 175.2 96 173.3z" fill="#d03f3f"/>
                                      <path d="M215.2 200c-3.6 3-9.8 1-13.8-4.1-4.2-5.2-4.6-11.5-1.2-14.1 3.6-2.8 9.7-.7 13.9 4.4 4 5.2 4.6 11.4 1.1 13.8z" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <path d="M428.4 201.3c0 49.2-74.4 94.2-74.4 94.2s-74.3-45-74.3-94.2a38 38 0 0 1 74.4-11.1 38 38 0 0 1 74.3 11.1z" fill="#e24b4b"/>
                                      <path d="M292.2 173.3a37.7 37.7 0 0 0-12.4 28c0 49.2 74.3 94.2 74.3 94.2-77.8-65.7-62.4-120.3-61.9-122.2z" fill="#d03f3f"/>
                                      <path d="M411.3 200c-3.6 3-9.8 1-13.8-4.1-4.2-5.2-4.6-11.5-1.2-14.1 3.6-2.8 9.7-.7 13.9 4.4 4 5.2 4.6 11.4 1.1 13.8z" fill="#fff"/>
                                      <path d="M381.7 374.1c-30.2 35.9-75.3 64.4-125.7 64.4s-95.4-28.5-125.8-64.2a17.6 17.6 0 0 1 16.5-28.7 627.7 627.7 0 0 0 218.7-.1c16.2-2.7 27 16.1 16.3 28.6z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <path d="M256 438.5c25.7 0 50-7.5 71.7-19.5-9-33.7-40.7-43.3-62.6-31.7-29.7 15.8-62.8-4.7-75.6 34.3 20.3 10.4 42.8 17 66.5 17z" fill="#e24b4b"/>
                                    </svg>
                                      <svg class="rating-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                      <g fill="#ffd93b">
                                        <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256"/>
                                        <path d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.8 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58 47 95.2 118.8 95.2 199.3z"/>
                                      </g>
                                      <path d="M512 99.4v165.1c0 11-8.9 19.9-19.7 19.9h-187c-13 0-23.5-10.5-23.5-23.5v-21.3c0-12.9-8.9-24.8-21.6-26.7-16.2-2.5-30 10-30 25.5V261c0 13-10.5 23.5-23.5 23.5h-187A19.7 19.7 0 0 1 0 264.7V99.4c0-10.9 8.8-19.7 19.7-19.7h472.6c10.8 0 19.7 8.7 19.7 19.7z" fill="#e9eff4"/>
                                      <path d="M204.6 138v88.2a23 23 0 0 1-23 23H58.2a23 23 0 0 1-23-23v-88.3a23 23 0 0 1 23-23h123.4a23 23 0 0 1 23 23z" fill="#45cbea"/>
                                      <path d="M476.9 138v88.2a23 23 0 0 1-23 23H330.3a23 23 0 0 1-23-23v-88.3a23 23 0 0 1 23-23h123.4a23 23 0 0 1 23 23z" fill="#e84d88"/>
                                      <g fill="#38c0dc">
                                        <path d="M95.2 114.9l-60 60v15.2l75.2-75.2zM123.3 114.9L35.1 203v23.2c0 1.8.3 3.7.7 5.4l116.8-116.7h-29.3z"/>
                                      </g>
                                      <g fill="#d23f77">
                                        <path d="M373.3 114.9l-66 66V196l81.3-81.2zM401.5 114.9l-94.1 94v17.3c0 3.5.8 6.8 2.2 9.8l121.1-121.1h-29.2z"/>
                                      </g>
                                      <path d="M329.5 395.2c0 44.7-33 81-73.4 81-40.7 0-73.5-36.3-73.5-81s32.8-81 73.5-81c40.5 0 73.4 36.3 73.4 81z" fill="#3e4347"/>
                                      <path d="M256 476.2a70 70 0 0 0 53.3-25.5 34.6 34.6 0 0 0-58-25 34.4 34.4 0 0 0-47.8 26 69.9 69.9 0 0 0 52.6 24.5z" fill="#e24b4b"/>
                                      <path d="M290.3 434.8c-1 3.4-5.8 5.2-11 3.9s-8.4-5.1-7.4-8.7c.8-3.3 5.7-5 10.7-3.8 5.1 1.4 8.5 5.3 7.7 8.6z" fill="#fff" opacity=".2"/>
                                    </svg>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <!-- 07 - Closing the PHP Loop -->
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And here the css:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.rating {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.rating-0 {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.rating > input {
  display: none;
}

.rating > label {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='126.729' height='126.73'%3e%3cpath fill='%23e3e3e3' d='M121.215 44.212l-34.899-3.3c-2.2-.2-4.101-1.6-5-3.7l-12.5-30.3c-2-5-9.101-5-11.101 0l-12.4 30.3c-.8 2.1-2.8 3.5-5 3.7l-34.9 3.3c-5.2.5-7.3 7-3.4 10.5l26.3 23.1c1.7 1.5 2.4 3.7 1.9 5.9l-7.9 32.399c-1.2 5.101 4.3 9.3 8.9 6.601l29.1-17.101c1.9-1.1 4.2-1.1 6.1 0l29.101 17.101c4.6 2.699 10.1-1.4 8.899-6.601l-7.8-32.399c-.5-2.2.2-4.4 1.9-5.9l26.3-23.1c3.8-3.5 1.6-10-3.6-10.5z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 76%;
  transition: .3s;
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label ~ label {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='126.729' height='126.73'%3e%3cpath fill='%23fcd93a' d='M121.215 44.212l-34.899-3.3c-2.2-.2-4.101-1.6-5-3.7l-12.5-30.3c-2-5-9.101-5-11.101 0l-12.4 30.3c-.8 2.1-2.8 3.5-5 3.7l-34.9 3.3c-5.2.5-7.3 7-3.4 10.5l26.3 23.1c1.7 1.5 2.4 3.7 1.9 5.9l-7.9 32.399c-1.2 5.101 4.3 9.3 8.9 6.601l29.1-17.101c1.9-1.1 4.2-1.1 6.1 0l29.101 17.101c4.6 2.699 10.1-1.4 8.899-6.601l-7.8-32.399c-.5-2.2.2-4.4 1.9-5.9l26.3-23.1c3.8-3.5 1.6-10-3.6-10.5z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.rating > input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover ~ label {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='126.729' height='126.73'%3e%3cpath fill='%23d8b11e' d='M121.215 44.212l-34.899-3.3c-2.2-.2-4.101-1.6-5-3.7l-12.5-30.3c-2-5-9.101-5-11.101 0l-12.4 30.3c-.8 2.1-2.8 3.5-5 3.7l-34.9 3.3c-5.2.5-7.3 7-3.4 10.5l26.3 23.1c1.7 1.5 2.4 3.7 1.9 5.9l-7.9 32.399c-1.2 5.101 4.3 9.3 8.9 6.601l29.1-17.101c1.9-1.1 4.2-1.1 6.1 0l29.101 17.101c4.6 2.699 10.1-1.4 8.899-6.601l-7.8-32.399c-.5-2.2.2-4.4 1.9-5.9l26.3-23.1c3.8-3.5 1.6-10-3.6-10.5z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.emoji-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.emoji-wrapper:before,
.emoji-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.emoji-wrapper:before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

.emoji-wrapper:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white 0%, white 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

.emoji {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transition: .3s;
}

.emoji > svg {
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#rating-1:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
          transform: translateY(-100px);
}

#rating-2:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
          transform: translateY(-200px);
}

#rating-3:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-300px);
          transform: translateY(-300px);
}

#rating-4:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px);
          transform: translateY(-400px);
}

#rating-5:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-500px);
          transform: translateY(-500px);
}

.feedback {
  max-width: 360px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

**What Is my doubt:**

Conceptually speaking, how should I create this page ?

I only want a very simple HTML page that displays the result of a database table (a list of movies in this case) and I would like to rate each one individualy.

I don't mind to use also javascript if it's necessary, the only requirement is that I should use PHP as my system is PHP based.

And idea of how can I do this ?

Does anyone could be kind to put a very simple example considering mysql/php ?

I appreciate any help I can get in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code examples of what you have. We can help advise on how these could be improved. Unfortunately, the scope of your question as is makes it far too broad to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: it sounds like you have hooked your libs/trys onto the dom using an id and then that same id is used for all items/movies. for anything multiple you use a class, and when accessing the click or element you use *this* context not re-query by id or something. please show your code/attempt

Comment: Ok Peter thank's for the suggestion, I have included the code to see if this can help somehow, on commented item 05 I can change to any other rating system I usually have the same results.

Comment: Hi Lawrence, I have included the code maybe this can help a little bit better to understand what I'm possible doing very wrong. Thanks in advance.